# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

Выходит ошибка при запуске. Ругается на то, что не может создать бин.

> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'defined in mypackage.config.PersistenceContext: Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V]]

Использую JPA, а в качестве провайдера Hibernate.

Собственно классы:

1. PersistentContext.java

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableTransactionManagement
   @ComponentScan(basePackages = "mypackage", excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Configuration.class))
   @PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
   @EnableJpaRepositories("mypackage.repository")
   public class PersistenceContext {

   @Autowired
   Environment environment;

   @Bean
   public DataSource dataSource() {
       DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
       dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.driver"));
       dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.url"));
       dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.username"));
       dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.password"));
       return dataSource;
   }

   @Bean
   public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
       LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
       entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());

       HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
       //hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
       entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibernateJpaVendorAdapter);
       entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(environment.getRequiredProperty("entitymanager.packages.to.scan"));

       Properties properties = new Properties();
       properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
       properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
       properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
       properties.setProperty("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans"));

       entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(properties);
       return entityManagerFactory;
   }

   @Bean
   public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
       JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
       jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
       return jpaTransactionManager;
   }
   }
   ```
2. WebAppInitializer.java

   ```
   public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
       @Override
       protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
           return new Class<?>[]{WebConfig.class,PersistenceContext.class};
       }

       @Override
       protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
           return new Class<?>[]{WebConfig.class};
       }

       @Override
       protected String[] getServletMappings() {
           return new String[]{"/"};
       }
   }
   ```
3. WebConfig.java

   ```
   @Configuration

   @EnableWebMvc

   @ComponentScan(basePackages = "mypackage", excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Configuration.class))

   public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
   @Bean
   public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
   InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
   viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
   viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
   viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
   return viewResolver;
   }
   }
   ```

Может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой.

Comment: при запуске, наверное, а не при компиляции

Comment: Ошибся. Да,при запуске.

Comment: Проблему решил, всем спасибо. Был глюк какой-то с сервером.

Answer (score 3):

*Несмотря на то, что автор решил проблему, я, пожалуй, оставлю свой ответ на случай если кто-то другой столкнётся с подобным.*

Ошибка `NoSuchMethodError` чаще всего возникает при конфликте версий библиотек, подключённых к проекту. Судя по логу, проблема возникает с классом `org.jboss.logging.Logger`. Проверьте, какую версию библиотеки `jboss-logger` требуют другие библиотеки, и какая версия в действительности подключается к исполняемому файлу. Чтобы узнать, какая библиотека в действительности подключается к проекту - проверяйте classpath. Если вы используете Maven, вы можете просмотреть дерево зависимостей при помощи команды `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`. Если вы не используете Maven (или другой инструмент управления зависимостями), то, чёрт возьми, начните его использовать - сэкономите кучу времени и сил.

Comment: добавлю - такая штука может быть при dependency hell в uberjar, когда одна версия библиотеки тупо записывается поверх другой. На этапе компиляции всем кажется, что всё в порядке, на деле в уберджаре присутствует класс без нужного метода или с неправильной сигнатурой.